# Web Scraping by using "Next" button Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am getting reviews for a webpage and need to scan each page until there are no longer any reviews left. Reviews page have multiple pages, and my first thought was to use a While loop, however, I am unsure where to start. HTML code of the web page looks something similar to this. 
[image]

HTML Code in last page;[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show code you have tried so far. Also share `HTML` of the last page

Comment: Check if URL has page as a parameter. If it does, you don't need to use next button. And for parsing html I would suggest [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc)

Comment: URL doesn't have a page parameter. I couldn't come up with something for looping. Any code suggestions are very welcomed. @Andersson

Comment: Show `HTML` code of `Next` button on the very last page

Comment: On the very last page next button does not exist, therefore no HTML code for that. I just edited my question and added the html code for last page. @Andersson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to click `Next` while it can be found:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.some_site.com")
while True:
    # do whatever you want
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a/span[text()="Next"]').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Comment: I am getting this error: NameError: global name 'driver' is not defined. I did not use Selenium before, my code uses urllib2 to request and BeautifulSoup to parse. @Andersson

Comment: Answer updated. If you use `http` requests to get page `HTML` source, why do you need `selenium` at all?

Comment: in order to use the html code browser-like, to click on next buttons. I could not find any other direct way to do this than Selenium.

Comment: Does my answer was helpful? Did you get rid of exception?